# i have try a lot of ways but the data from table in controller didn't pass to view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

Laravel Framework 9.13.0

CategoryController

```
 public function index()
{
    $cate= Category::all();
    return view("admin.category", compact('cate'));
}
```

category.blade.php

```
            @php($i=1);
            @foreach($cate as $category)
                    <td> {{ $i++ }} </td>
                    <td>{{ $category->CategoryName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $category->created_at }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $category->Updated_at }}</td>

            @endforeach
            @endphp
```

the result display like this:

{{ $i++ }}  {{ $category->CategoryName }}   {{ $category->created_at }} {{ $category->Updated_at }}

If i remove @php and @endPhp, the result display nothing.

the info dd($cate); show like this

```
 ^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1212 ▼
   #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Category {#1214 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "categories"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
       #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "CategoryName" => "White Skate"
        "created_at" => "2022-06-06 02:03:13"
        "Updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "CategoryName" => "White Skate"
        "created_at" => "2022-06-06 02:03:13"
        "Updated_at" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just mixed up some things here. You can do it like this (not tested):

`CategoryController.php`

```php
use App\Models\Category;

public function category()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('admin.category', ['cate' => $categories]);
}
```

`category.blade.php`

```php
@foreach($cate as $category)
   {{ $category->CategoryName }}
   {{ $category->DateCreate }}
   {{ $category->DateUpdate }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i have used that method too, the result display the same. is it because of im not using models or i use the latest framework? i'm thinking downgrade to 5.5v

Comment: It is probably because you are not using models. Please provide the output of `dd($cate);` in your controller or view and post the result.

Comment: ^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#287 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#289 ▶}
    1 => {#291 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
output of dd($cate); in my controller

Comment: Please post it formatted into your main post. I can't read anything like that. also click the triangle for the array so it folds out and we can see the insides.

Comment: dd($cate);  already add .i have switch to use eloquent but the result the same.

Comment: Yes. Your result looks totally good. Is the result the same if you write `{{ dd($cate) }}` inside your view? (Remember to remove the `dd()` from your Controller!!!)

Comment: yeah, the result is the same, why the the data didnt show when i loop

Comment: It should absolutely show. Is that the whole view file or just an excerpt? Please show the full view. If it was already everything, I have no idea why the `@foreach` shouldn't be working. Used it hundreds of times this way.

Comment: i found out the problem. because of i used for loop inside php that's why forloop didn't work. thank for keep up and help me.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the problem. Because of i use @forloop inside @php that's why the @forloop didnt work. it should be like this

```
 @php
     $i=1
 @endphp
 @foreach($cate as $category)
     {{ $i++ }}
     {{$category->CategoryName}}
     {{$category->created_at}}
      {{$category->Updated_at}}
                                                                                
 @endforeach
```

Comment: That was one of the first things we mentioned... You don't even need the `$i` variable. Inside the loop you can access the current index with `$loop->index`

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to loop inside the controller,

- bring the whole array to view  `return View('admin.category')->with('category',$cate);`
- loop the array inside the view.

```
  @if(count($cate) > 0):
     @foreach ($cate as $cate):
        // your code
     @endforeach
  @endif
```

Comment: i loop inside the controller to make sure that the table connect and the data store inside variable and the method u mention i already try too. it didnt work

Comment: is there any error you are seeing on the screen  or use `ddd` and provide the error dump to understand it better